# I want my php form to submit data and redirect on the same page but different tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, mysql

I have a Create resume page with four different parts on the same page, every section has its own database table. I want when it is submitted for it to redirect on another id which I've given in the submit button.

[image]

```
<div class="panel-body">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified m-12" role="tablist">
   <li id="li1" class="active border-right"><a href="#cinfo"  role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Contact Information</a></li>
   <li id="li2"><a href="#binfo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Basic Information</a></li>
   <li id="li3"><a href="#einfo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Education Details</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="cinfo">
      <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <div class="form-group col-md-6 p-r">
            <label>Professional Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" required="required" />
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-6 p-l">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" required="required" />
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-6 p-r">
            <label>Last name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" required="required" />
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-6 p-l">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="mail" class="form-control" required="required" />
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-6 p-r">
            <label>Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" required="required" />
         </div>
         <!-- <div class="col-md-4 p-l"> -->
         <a href="#binfo"><button id="btn1" type="submit" name="cinfo_btn" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Next</button></a>
         <!-- </div> -->
      </form>
   </div>
   <!-- Basic Information -->
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="binfo">
      <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <div class="form-group col-md-6 p-l">
            <label>Job Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="jobtitle" class="form-control" />
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-6 p-r">
            <label>Position</label>
            <input type="text" name="position" class="form-control" />
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-6 p-l">
            <label>Years of Experience</label>
            <input type="text" name="exp" class="form-control" />
         </div>
         <a href="#einfo"><button id="btn2" type="submit" name="einfo_btn" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Next</button></a>
         <!-- </div> -->
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use ajax call for this

Comment: Add `PHP` code too

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for you would be to use ajax.
Submit the first form using ajax then in response success callback
just trigger click event on on the next tab then it will take to you tab you have specified.

> > this take the tab to 2nd tab.

```
 request1 = $.ajax({
            url: "url",
            type: "POST",
            data:  yourdata
        });
        request1.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              $('#li2').trigger('click')
         });
```

> > this take the tab to 3rd tab.

```
 request2= $.ajax({
            url: "url",
            type: "POST",
            data:  yourdata
        });
        request2.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
              $('#li3').trigger('click')
         });
```